# Android File manipulation tests with JUNIT

Tags: java, android, eclipse, junit

I am trying to test file manipulation with my APP. First of all I wanna check that whenever I call a function that reads the file, this function will throw an Exception because the file isn't there.

However, I don't seem to understand how to achieve this... This is the code I designed, but it doesn't run ... the normal JUNIT says the FILEPATH wasn't found, the android JUNIT says, the Test could not be run.

The folder: /data/data/example.triage/files/ is already available in the virtual device...

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    dr = new DataReader();
    dw = new DataWriter();
    DefaultValues.file_path_folder = "/data/data/example.triage/files/";
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {

    dr = null;
    dw = null;

    // Remove the patients file we may create in a test.
    dr.removeFile(DefaultValues.patients_file_path);

}

@Test
public void readHealthCardsNonExistentPatientsFile() {

    try {
        List<String> healthcards = dr.getHealthCardsofPatients();
        fail("The method didn't generate an Exception when the file wasn't found.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        assertTrue(e.getClass().equals(FileNotFoundException.class));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are checking for the exception in a way that correlates with the JUnit API.

Have you tried to make the call:

```
@Test (expected = Exception.class)
public void tearDown() {

    // code that throws an exception

}
```

I don't think you want the `setup()` function to be able to generate an exception, since it is called before all other test cases.

Here's another way to test exceptions:

```
Exception occurred = null;
try
{
    // Some action that is intended to produce an exception
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    occurred = exception;
}
assertNotNull(occurred);
assertTrue(occurred instanceof /* desired exception type */);
assertEquals(/* expected message */, occurred.getMessage());
```

So I would make you `setup()` code not throw an exception and move the exception generating code to a test method, using an appropriate way to test for it.

Comment: SetUp doesn't generate an exception... it just creates new instances of the objects im checking..

Comment: Okay perfect. I'd remove the `throws Exception` tag on the `setup()` method, then since you don't need it. Does the rewrite of `tearDown()` fix the JUnit problem?

Comment: I realized the problem is the way the testing works... In order to test the behaviour of an Android app, you need a new app that opens the to-be-tested-app and analyses the variables. I fixed the problem by creating a new project for this purpose.